# Почему в WP когда создаешь страницу, ссылка работает, если выбираешь parent ошибка 404?

Tags: php, wordpress

стоит задача создать дочерние страницы от родительской страницы Services в WP, как правильно это сделать ? Сейчас я создаю страницу через админку, выбираю родительскую Services ошибка 404, как это исправить ? Заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите больше деталей, потому что по-умолчанию этот функционал работает без проблем.

Comment: Дочерних страниц не бывает. Есть Иерархия через категории и подкатегории.

Comment: @Sergio да ладно, а что на счет `Page Attributes -> Parent` [How to Create a Child Page in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-create-a-child-page-in-wordpress/) и все остальное связанное с их выводом, к примеру [get_page_children()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_page_children) и тд и тп.

Comment: Да, согласен, я балбес. Не пользуюсь этим, а посему и вообще не обращаю внимания. Всё это на мой взгляд от Лукавого, мне хватает меток, категорий.

Comment: "выбираю родительскую Services ошибка 404", родительская опубликована?